# What are inline PHP tags utilizing the PHP shortcut operator?

Tags: php, inline

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
           <body>
                 <h1>Welcome to Our Website!</h1>
                 <hr/>
                 <h2>News</h2>
                 <h4><?=$data['title'];?></h4>
                 <p><?=$data['content'];?></p>
           </body>
    </html>
```

Can anyone tell me what's the "=" sign before variable names ? I thought of some echo alias but I couldn't find anything, thanks for your help

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: Hi, this usage is not recommended. Use full php `<?php ?>` notations. I mean `<?php echo $variable; ?>`

Comment: "I thought of some echo alias but I couldn't find anything" Yeah because there is nothing in the official manual on the [`echo` page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) about it

Comment: @vaibhavmande Why isn't it recommended? Using `<?` is not recommended, but `<?=` is something different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: @ElonThan Short tags are not enabled on all servers, so code using them is not very portable.

Comment: @aynber From 5.4 short tags are not required anymore. I thought it was from 5.2, so you're still right :)

Answer (score 1):

`<?=$a?>` is the shortcut for `<? echo $a ?>`, they are called "short tags" in PHP terminology

Check PHP documentation [Escaping from HTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) example #2 3rd item, and related ini setting [short-open-tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

Answer (score 0):

This tag is interpreted as `<?php echo`.

You can check it by writing `<?= ?>`, you'll receive error.